# <textarea> not accepting initial value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

In my view I have a textarea that needs to be initialized by a value retrieved from database.
I coded:

```
<textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control">@ViewBag.Product.Description</textarea>
```

but when the page is displayed the field doesn't come populated. 
If I use an input text field it works:

```
<input asp-for="Description" type="text" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.Product.Description" />
```

I already tried another way using @Html.TextArea and does not work too:

```
@{
  var vDescription = ViewBag.Product.Description;
}
@Html.TextArea("Description", vDescription, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

What is wrong? What do I need to do?

Comment: Murat, It didn't work. TextArea doesn't recognize a "Value" parameter. When executing as you suggested it returns: "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"

Comment: Have you tried to apply my **updated** answer? Please do not forget to mark it as answer if it is helpful. Thanks...

Comment: Yes, I tried and didn't work. It doesn't even work if I put a fixed text like: ```<textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control">Test</textarea>``` . I really need the asp-for clause since the value need to be returned to the controller via the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for razor view:

```
@{
    //check if the value is null and then remove this part
    var vDescription = ViewBag.Product.Description;
}
@Html.TextArea("Description", ViewBag.Product.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

If it does not work, use this:

```
<textarea id="description" ame="Description">@ViewBag.Product.Description</textarea>
```

Comment: It didn't work. TextArea doesn't recognize a "Value" parameter. When executing as you suggested it returns: "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference".

Comment: I updated my answer, check the value first if it is not null, it should work. Let me about the result.

Comment: Murat, the value is not null, but when inside the <textarea> tag it appears to be null. If I insert a <label> after <textarea> it shows the description without problem: ```<label>@ViewBag.Product.Description</label>```  . It appears to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control">@ViewBag.Product.Description</textarea>
```

This is a wrong implementation, when you say `asp-for="Description"` the field value will be filled from the `"Description"` and not from the inner html of the textarea tags.

You can do one of these implementations:

- Assign the `Description` value in the backend before passing to the view, then you can use it like below:

```html
<textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

- or just manually define the textarea name and inner html:

```html
<textarea name="Description" class="form-control">@ViewBag.Product.Description</textarea>
```

Comment: It didn't work. When inside the <textarea> tag the value in @ViewBag appears to be null, but it is not. If I insert a <label> after <textarea> it shows the description without problem: ```<label>@ViewBag.Product.Description</label>```  . Why does it act differently with a textarea? It appears to be a bug.

Comment: Can you try using `ViewData` instead of `ViewBag`?

Comment: I tried using ViewData. Does not work too. In fact ViewData are ViewBag are the same resource with different syntax.